# Shorthand for selector in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to avoid duplicating "selector" in Jquery.
I need someway like using "this" keyword in JavaScript, I don't want to declare 
another variable because in this case I have to declare a lot if I have long
code.
example:

```
if ($(obj).parent().find(".ValidationErrors").length && 
    $(obj).parent().find(".ValidationErrors").text().indexOf("Max") < 0) {
  return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Given your code sample there's no real alternative to creating a variable to hold the reference to your `.ValidateErrors` elements. However you can shorten the `return` to just include the outcome of the condition. Try this:

```
var $errors = $(obj).parent().find(".ValidationErrors")
return !($errors.length && $errors.text().indexOf("Max") < 0);
```

In fact the `length` check is redundant as jQuery will return a string from `text()`, even if the element doesn't exist, so the logic can be shortened further to just:

```
return $(obj).parent().find(".ValidationErrors").text().indexOf("Max") != -1;
```

Comment: could you please answer me if this way is not efficient:
if ((error=$(obj).parent().find(".ValidationErrors")).length){error.remove();}

Comment: I'd be more concerned about the logic an syntax than the efficiency. I'm confused about your use of `error`. Setting it equal to the `length` in the condition is very odd, especially as you then call `remove()` on it, as if it were a jQuery object